# In SQL, how can I delete duplicate rows based on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, no-duplicates

I know I can run the following query below to find "duplicate" rows based on multiple columns doing something like this:

```
SELECT      PosId, OrgId
FROM        PosOrg
GROUP BY    PosId, OrgId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but now I want to delete the duplicate rows so the above query ends of returning zero rows.  I don't care which of the rows that I delete (just as long as only one rows remains based on the uniqueness of those two columns.

What is the correct way to delete these duplicates in SQL?

Comment: What are the other columns on that table? Is there a PK constraint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have another unique `id` column you can do

```
delete from PosOrg
where id not in
(
  SELECT      min(id)
  FROM        PosOrg
  GROUP BY    PosId, OrgId
)
```

Comment: wouldn't i need a "where > 1" somewhere on this?

Comment: No, you delete all records that are not `min(id)` for every group, meaning all duplicates

Comment: @leora no, not if there is a unique field called ID on the table. You should add to your question whether or not there is such a field.

Answer (score 7):

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT PosId
          ,OrgId
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PosId , OrgId ORDER BY PosId , OrgId) rn
    FROM   PosOrg
   )
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
```